Why is AddressBook.msg compiled as address_book.hpp in ROS2
I am a new ROS2 learner. I am practicing "Implementing custom interfaces" from ROS2 DOCS
On step 2, it require to creat a file called AddressBook.msg But on step 3, it required to creat a file called publish_address_book.cpp, and one line code  of this file is #include "more_interfaces/msg/address_book.hpp".
I was wondering if address_book.hpp compiled from AddressBook.msg. If yes, why there is an underline between address and book.
Thanks for your help.

The header address_book.hpp is generated during the colcon build process from the AddressBook.msg file. colcon will name these header files after the naming convention, so it will remove all uppercase letters and add underscores.
The naming convention of the message file can be found here or read the following discourse on discource.ros2.org
